# When u download additional libraries & add their features to ur c++ program, would u be able to run ur software on another PC (w/o the library)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

Quick question here, okay say that I have downloaded additional libraries and added them to my version of visual studios and have their #include  and commands in my project source code.

If I was to take the .cpp file and bring it to my school computer which also has visual studios and doesn't have these additional libraries, it would have a bunch of missing errors and can't compile.

but..

What if I publish my project and I have it in a .exe file and I was to try and run it on another computer that doesn't have these libraries? Would the executable file run okay?

Comment: Please use real words when posting here. "u", "ur", and "w/o" are not words. You're not texting here; there's plenty of space, we don't charge by the letter, and this is a professional site. You're not chatting with your buddies. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you

```
#include <stuff>
```

*stuff* is used during compilation time. However, the libraries it may refer to (e.g. the *include* gives the definition of many functions from an external library), can be

- static or
- dynamic

*static* libraries are linked statically when the program is built, and are part of the executable. *dynamic* libraries like DLL are linked during the *execution* of the program .exe. Thus they (DLL) may not be present on another computer when you run the same exe on it.

It depends on the libraries you are using, but sometimes a package is available for download and installation on the other computer, so that they become available. Sometimes you have to copy a bunch of DLLs along with your exe to the other computer. For instance, some [advice from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kche8ah.aspx) in this regard.